# Write any document file to file manager in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsfilemanager

Is it possible to write any file to the Files App in iOS11?
I want to write any document file to the Files App which was introduced in iOS 11, so is there any way to perform this operation, I try to find on google but did not get any solution.

Comment: There is no `public API` for reading and writing into `File Manager` app

Comment: Note that all Apps are sandboxed. They can not read/write each others directories but you can export any file to other App's that can handle them.